# Android Image Button Issue

Tags: android, icons, imagebutton

I have the following imageButton

```
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/header_buttonleft"
    android:layout_width="40dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_download"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

But when I load my application in the device, it appears too small:

[image]

Anyone knows how can I make the icon bigger. I have tried to increase the resolution (actually the icon is 70x70) but it still doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Anyone knows how can i make the icon
>   bigger.

Make a bigger button.

As an experiment, remove `android:src` from your layout, then run your app. That is the *smallest* an `ImageButton` can go without a custom background.

You are welcome to create your own custom `ImageButton` background with custom nine-patch PNG files for the different background states, where you adjust the nine-patch control frame to allow for a smaller gap between where your icon goes and the edges of the button.

Comment: Solved. The problem was folders drawable-hdpi, mdpi... 

I was putting the icons on folder hdpi instead mdpi.

Thanks